# how to get byte[] for Image on Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using **Xamarin.Forms**, So when I am trying to choose photo from Gallery(I used [https://components.xamarin.com/view/mediaplugin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/mediaplugin/%22Media%20Plugin%22) to handle with photos ), I need to get `byte[]` for image to use it on web service, how I can do that.

Check My Code on the Following:

```
ChoosePhotoButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
        return;
    }
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();


    if (file == null)
        return;

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });
    OptionalInfoPage.DriverImage = image;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it from file  directly by use `file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream)`check  the following code :

```
  using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
   {
          file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
       // file.Dispose();
          byte[] ImageBytes  = memoryStream.ToArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing well if your code is returning a valid stream! just try adding this instead of returning the stream ,,

```
byte[] ImageBytes = stream.ToArray();
return ImageBytes;
```